# WPFComboBox Value for Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create little GUI in Visual Studio that runs on PowerShell for a task that the user will select an application from a drop down, then press an add button. I can't seem to figure out how to bind/map the selection to a value the script will get. Here's my list:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="270,330,0,0">
  <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Avaya_CMS" Content="Avaya CMS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="118"/>
  <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Avaya_OneX" Content="Avaya One X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="118"/>
  <ComboBoxItem x:Name="ControlM" Content="Control-M" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="118"/>
  <ComboBoxItem x:Name="IBM_DB2" Content="IBM DB2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="118"/>
  <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Project_2010" Content="MS Project 2010" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="118"/>
  <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Visio_2010" Content="MS Visio 2010" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="118"/>
  <ComboBoxItem x:Name="SCCM" Content="SCCM Console" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="118"/>
</ComboBox>
<Button x:Name="Go" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="413,330,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48"/>
```

I have used display member binding for output to a display but this is my first go at a ComboBox.

Comment: `$ComboBox = $WpfForm.FindName("comboBox")` then call `$ComboBox.Items.Add()` from the Button's event handler

Comment: You should really check out [this blog's series](http://foxdeploy.com/resources/learning-gui-toolmaking-series/) about this topic. Check out the XAML/VS parts 1-4, and I think part 2 is the one that will go through combo boxes if I remember right.